# Any example for Security of .Net Desktop application

Tags: .net, code-access-security

Is it possible to prevent any unauthorised user to access code or application in desktop application like any web application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to protect your sourcecode, I would use an obfuscator like the free Eazfuscator.NET

http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net

UPDATE: no longer free since June 29, 2012

Answer (score 1):

You can use the imperative [PrincipalPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.aspx) or the declarative [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx) to assert that a user meets some authorization criteria to invoke a certain method or block of code.

This resource describes how to use this kind of security. In my experience, this pattern works best (where "best" means "easiest to set up") in an ActiveDirectory environment.

http://www.ginktage.com/2010/03/role-based-security-in-net/